# Embed a R network map (saved as html file) in powerpoint?

Tags: r, vba, powerpoint

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
WebBrowser1.Navigate ("file:///C:/test.html")
End Sub
```

I'm trying to embed a local html file as a web object in power point. The above code is working fine for website links, but when I replace it with a local file, nothing is displayed.

The HTML file has a lot of JS, which is being called in the body. Basically I created a network map in R, saved it in .html format and I'm trying to embed it in powerpoint. When I call the html file in powerpoint, I get the notification "To help protect your security, your computer has restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls that could access your computer".

The file does not load in powerpoint.

Comment: Where are you creating WebBrowser1?

Comment: It's a Microsoft Browser object that I have created in PowerPoint, where I'll be displaying the output.